# Select sub-sequences in lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a list like the following one

```
list = { { a1 , {b1,c1} } , { a2 , {b2,c2} } , { a3 , {b3,c3} } };
```

I would like to select a sub-sequence from this list such that the output reads

> `{ { a1 , c1 } , { a2 , c2 } , { a3 , c3 } }`

To get this, I have tried the following:

```
list[[ ;; , {1,{2}} ]]
```

but Mathematica complains that this is not valid input. How should I make the selection properly?

EDIT:

It is great to see so many different solutions being suggested!
I would just like to point out that the ideal solution should be accessing the list "in place" as in:

```
list2 = { {d1,e1} , {d2,e2} , {d3,e3} };
list[[ ;; , {1,{2}} ]] = list2;
list
```

> `{ { d1 , {b1,e1} } , { d2 , {b2,e2} } , { d3 , {b3,e3} } }`

where I used my wrong syntax from above that does not actually work to demonstrate the point.

EDIT2:

Of course there is nothing particularly special or important about the specific dimensions and arrangement of the elements in `list`. A solution that would be useful in general should allow to specify the parts one needs from all sorts of list structures.

Comment: `{#, #2[[-1]]} & @@@ list` or `{#[[1]], #[[2, -1]]} & /@ list`?

Comment: @kglr I see, yes, such maps should work, thank you. For some reason I was expecting mathematica to also be able to access the fields in place without writing a new list, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: I don't know you like it but here is another way to get your output. `Partition[Flatten@list, 3][[;; , {1, 3}]]`

Comment: I have [provided benchmarks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/175888/10397) for all the solutions provided so far, with  @AlexeyPopkov been the fastest for long lists.

Comment: All 10 solutions so far seems very *hacky* to me, and it's somehow disappointing that  `Part` doesn't allow what the OP expected with `list[[All, {1,{2}} ]]`, probably with a different syntax..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Task

Basically you want a Part function which accepts *positional arguments*. Let us extend the example a little further to get more levels:

```
list = {
   {a1, {b1, c1}, d1, {e1, {f1, g1}}},
   {a2, {b2, c2}, d2, {e2, {f2, g2}}},
   {a3, {b3, c3}, d3, {e3, {f3, g3}}}
 };
```

Suppose we want all `a`, `c` and `g`s, the partspec would be:

```
list[[All, {1, {2}, {}, {{}, {2}}}]];

partspec = {1, {2}, {}, {{}, {2}}};
```

### Core Solution

We define a function which will resolve positional part arguments. First we retrieve the positions for all atomic values:

```
positions = Position[partspec, _?AtomQ, Heads -> False]
```

> {{1}, {2, 1}, {4, 2, 1}}

All but the last indices give us the position we need to extract later. The last index, however, has to be replaced with the actual number that was given in partspec:

```
parts = MapThread[
 Join[Most@#1, {#2}] &,
 {positions, Extract[partspec, positions]}
]
```

> {{1}, {2, 2}, {4, 2, 2}}

The resolved partspec works with `Extract`:

```
Extract[#, parts] & /@ list
```

> {{a1, c1, g1}, {a2, c2, g2}, {a3, c3, g3}}

The final function is:

```
ResolvePositionalPartspec[partspec_] := 
 With[{positions = Position[partspec, _?AtomQ, Heads -> False]},
  MapThread[
   Join[Most@#1, {#2}] &,
   {positions, Extract[partspec, positions]}]
  ]
```

### Extended Solution

To be able to combine it with other partspecs such as `Range`s or `All`, let's define another function which applies the **ResolvePositionalPartspec** function only to list arguments in `Part`s:

```
PositionalPart[list_, partspec___] := Fold[
  #2[#1] &,
  list,
  Replace[{partspec},
   {listspec_List :> (Map[Extract[#, ResolvePositionalPartspec@listspec] &, #] &),
    otherspec_ :> (Part[#, otherspec] &)},
   {1}]
  ]
```

The idea is to replace each argument in the partspec with a pure function and subsequently apply it via **Fold**. Note that this does not exactly reproduce the behaviour of `Part` on subsequent levels, but I found it to be quite practical anyhow.

Now we can use it with our list:

```
PositionalPart[list, All, partspec]
```

> {{a1, c1, g1}, {a2, c2, g2}, {a3, c3, g3}}

```
PositionalPart[list, 1 ;; 2, partspec]
```

> {{a1, c1, g1}, {a2, c2, g2}}

It will fail when the first partspec does not give a list (since `Map`ping on level 1 is hard-coded in `PositionalPart`):

```
PositionalPart[list, 1, partspec]
```

> Extract::partd: Part specification {1} is longer than depth of object. >>

Use `PositionalPart[list, 1;;1, partspec]` instead. Note that     `PositionalPart[list, {1}, partspec]` will not work because `{1}` will be interpreted as a positional part argument, as in:

```
PositionalPart[list, {1}]
```

> {{a1}, {a2}, {a3}}

### Application

To use it an everyday coding, you can redefine `Part` to work the way `PositionalPart` does. When replacing Part, I would add something symbolic to the definition, similar to the `UpTo[]` function, like:

```
Part[list, All, Positional[{1, {2}, {}, {{}, {2}}}]]
```

This means you will not loose the regular `{}` syntax.

To achieve this, the `Replace` statement in `PositionalPart` would be modified to replace only specifications wrapped in `Positional[]` with the `Extract[ResolvePositionalPartspec]` function instead of replacing all lists.

Comment: I like this solution a lot due to its generality! I wonder if it uses the most efficient script to achieve the construction? Will wait a little bit, and if nothing else shows up, will accept this answer.

Comment: Glad you like it. I expect the `PositionalPart` function to be slower than regular `Part`s because it extracts each level in the `partspec` separately. To become a production-grade function this one has to be optimized a little more anyway (including some error checking and such). The core function, `ResolvePositionalPartspec`, seems fine and efficient to me, however.

Answer (score 8):

> I was expecting mathematica to also be able to access the fields in place without writing a new list

In-place modification approach:

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};
list[[;; , 2]] = list[[;; , 2, 2]];
list
```

> ```
> {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}
> ```

Comment: This is the fastest solution so far, but beware that you are redefining `list` and therefore loosing information. In the benchmarks I implemented your solution inside `Module[{modlist = list},...]` which is almost as fast without modifying the original `list`.

Answer (score 8):

### Other solutions

```
MapAt[Last, list, {All, 2}]
(* {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}} *)

list /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, z}
(* {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}} *)
```

### Benchmark

Large data, 10^7 lines.

```
largeList = 
  Table[{RandomReal[1], {RandomReal[1], RandomReal[1]}}, {10^7}];
```

[`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html)`@`[`AbsoluteTiming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteTiming.html)
returns the absolute number of seconds in real time that have elapsed during evaluation.

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[
  MapAt[Last, largeList, {All, 2}]
  ]
(* 4.86435 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  largeList /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, z}
  ]
(* 4.95776 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  Partition[Flatten@largeList, 3][[All, {1, 3}]]
  ]
(* 3.66688 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  {#, #2[[-1]]} & @@@ largeList
  ]
(* 8.83799 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  {#[[1]], #[[2, -1]]} & /@ largeList
  ]
(* 12.3966 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  Module[{modlist = largeList}
   , modlist[[;; , 2]] = modlist[[;; , 2, 2]]
   ]
  ]
(* 2.6865 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  Query[All, {1 -> Identity, 2 -> Last}]@largeList
  ]
(* 23.1379 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  {#, #2 & @@ #2} & @@@ largeList
  ]
(* 12.7286 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  {#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ largeList
  ]
(* 13.2996 *)

First@AbsoluteTiming[
  largeList[[;; , 2]] = largeList[[;; , 2, 2]]
  ]
(* 2.07737 *)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** Using a slightly modified version of the list of parts:

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};
parts = {{1}, {2, 2}};
list2 = {{d1, e1}, {d2, e2}, {d3, e3}};
Do[(list[[i, ##]] = list2[[i, #]]) & @@@ parts, {i, Length @ list2}]
list
```

> {{d1, {b1, e1}}, {d2, {b2, e2}}, {d3, {b3, e3}}}

Alternatively, you can use `ReplacePart`:

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};
list = ReplacePart[list, ({i_, ##} :> list2[[i, #]]) & @@@ parts];
list
```

> {{d1, {b1, e1}}, {d2, {b2, e2}}, {d3, {b3, e3}}}

**Original answer:**

Few additional alternatives:

```
Transpose@{list[[All, 1]], list[[All, 2, 2]]}
Cases[list , {a_, {b_, c_}} :> {a, c}]
Replace[list , {_, b_} :> b, {2}]
Query[All, {1 -> Identity, 2 -> Last}] @ list
{#, #2 & @@ #2} & @@@ list
{#, #2[[-1]]} & @@@ list
{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ list
```

all give

> {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0)

```
Comap[{First, Last @* Last}] /@ list
```

{{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}

Answer (score 3):

For the wanted in-place solution there is also `ApplyTo` (since V 12.2):

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};

list //= MapAt[Last, {All, 2}];

list
```

{{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};
```

Using `Thread`:

```
Last /@ Thread /@ list

(*{{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
list = {{a1, {b1, c1}}, {a2, {b2, c2}}, {a3, {b3, c3}}};

SubsetMap[Map[Last], list, {All, 2}]
```

> {{a1, c1}, {a2, c2}, {a3, c3}}